# Removing alphabets and special characters other than decimal point from a column in a pandas dataframe using regex not working as intended

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to remove labels like "kg", "g", "pack", "packs" from a column so I can perform a numerical operation, however for some reason its dropping a lot of values.

https://pastebin.com/pRtKsAYL

This is the line which I am using to remove anything other than digits in the df.

```
df['boxes'] = df['boxes'].str.replace(r'[^\d.]+', '')
```

Over 600 entries in the column boxes gets dropped even though they do not have any alphabets in them.

Is there something I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share a copy of the excel data as clear text instead of a link please?

Comment: Sure! https://pastebin.com/pRtKsAYL

Comment: What do you mean by entries getting dropped? Your regex seems to work fine for only keeping numerical values.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/nrgbnizS this is what shows if I uncomment that line, a lot of entries in  the box column just gets removed....

Comment: I cannot reproduce a misbehaviour, works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

I found if I added

```
concatenated['boxes'] = concatenated['boxes'].astype(str)
```

before

```
concatenated['boxes_cl']  = concatenated['boxes'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False)
```

It kinda works, but added nan to all the blank columns.